# Pardot Prospect Activities Date/Time mapped to a custom field of Salesforce

Tags: apex, lightning, callout, pardot, field-mapping

In Pardot we have a Prospect Activity tab as follows:
[image]

I want to have a custom field in Salesforce as **Form Handler Last Activity** and **Visit Last Activity** which will be equal to the latest Date/Time for these Activities. Ex. Here for this Prospect , In Salesforce

**Form Handler Last Activity** = Sep 8, 2020 11:21 AM ;
**Visit Last Activity** = Sep 9, 2020 8:08 AM

Can please someone suggest a way how this can be achieved as I am not able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use the Pardot API to accomplish this. In a regular interval, query Visitor activity (use form_handler_only=true for your Form Handler activity, type=20 for visits). Calculate/determine the latest respective visitor activity entry for each prospect then use the API to update each prospect (using either batch update or bulk update depending on your approach and volume)